# Can the sum, difference and product of 2 numbers be perfect squares?

Tags: mathematics, number-theory, algebra

If we take 2 numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $x>y>0$ and , can $x + y$, $x - y$ and $xy$ all be perfect squares?

Comment: Is this on topic? Feels like a math question

Comment: No I made it myself but could not solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is

> that they cannot.

Suppose $x+y=a^2$ and $x-y=b^2$. Then

> $x,y=\frac{a^2\pm b^2}2$ and therefore $4xy=a^4-b^4$. So if this too is a square we have $a^4-b^4=c^2$. Now see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153546/solving-x4-y4-z2 where it is shown that there are no solutions to this equation in nonzero integers.

Comment: "if this too is a square" we have (a^4 -b^4) / 4 = c^2 ...  The fact that you binned y=0 means that the proof doesn't hold for this alternate equation

Comment: If 4xy is a square then xy is also a square. I'm not sure what you mean by "you binned y=0" but the question itself specifies that y>0.

Answer (score 2):

(Before the OP clarifying that 0 is disallowed)

**Yes.**

> x = 4, y = 0; x+y = 4, x-y = 4, xy = 0. (x can be any perfect square, I just decided to use 4)

Comment: Sorry my fault, I meant to include that y cannot = 0.

Comment: But can x be 0?

Comment: If x were 0 y would be less than 0 making x + y negative and a negative number cannot be a perfect square